Problem with zooming in TOP view with ScatterVBO
Im using the scatterVBO class to draw a 5 000 000 million points chart. It gives a very good result like in this example https://github.com/jzy3d/bigpicture. However when I zoom in the view by using mouse selection pane, I begin to see the backgroung, and the wiew is degraded. Is there a way to avoid this ? I have not implemented any custom mouse controller on the TOP view mode. Im using the default one. Thanks
the view when I don't zoom in(just cropped for capture), the view when I zoom in with dark background. the view when I zoom in with white background
                                                                                                            .

